# Query Woocommerce Total Purchased Made By Current Login User

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My current function successfully query for the whole sales made in my website. But I'm not sure how to limit the amount only for current user who is login-in the system. I mean total purchased made by them. They will be able to see their total purchased. Current code below will display total sale made to that particular day.

My code

```
function get_daily_purchases_total(){
global $wpdb;

return $wpdb->get_var( "
    SELECT DISTINCT SUM(pm.meta_value)
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
    AND p.post_status IN ('wc-processing','wc-completed', 'wc-on-hold')
    AND DATE(p.post_date) >= CURDATE()
    AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_order_total'
" );
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce itself has a inbuilt function which is [wc_get_customer_total_spent()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_customer_total_spent.html#471-479) where user_id is the parameter, but as per your requirement i slightly modified the query which is used by [WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Customer_Data_Store.html#336-368)

```
function so_55556214_get_orders_from_user_id() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id > 0) {
        //run only for members
        $statuses = array('completed', 'processing', 'on-hold');
        global $wpdb;

        $result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT SUM(meta2.meta_value)
                    FROM $wpdb->posts as posts
                    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS meta ON posts.ID = meta.post_id
                    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS meta2 ON posts.ID = meta2.post_id
                    WHERE   meta.meta_key       = '_customer_user'
                    AND     meta.meta_value     = '" . esc_sql($user_id) . "'
                    AND     posts.post_type     = 'shop_order'
                    AND     posts.post_status   IN ( 'wc-" . implode("','wc-", $statuses) . "' )
                    AND     meta2.meta_key      = '_order_total'
                    AND DATE(posts.post_date) >= CURDATE() ");
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I tested the above code in my side and it seems work fine. Hope it helps :-)